# temporarily disabling a printer

Tags: catalina, printing

I have a printer that only works from the office and not from home.  The driver start searching at startup and shows a lot of pop-ups trying to connect. The driver is a custom HP printer driver from the office provider.

Is there any way to disable a printer driver temporarily via bash script or similar?   I'm using MacOS Catalina on a Macbook Pro 2020.

thanks

Comment: I've never known a printer be actively 'chased' before. My Printer [also an HP, on the network, not directly connected] spends most of its time switched off, so it's 'not there' as far as my Mac is concerned. It only starts to hunt if I ask it to print something.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah probably the driver is badly designed. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: im not user mac but you can try this https://support.apple.com/en-za/guide/mac-help/mchlf2272230/mac#:~:text=If%20you%20no%20longer%20use,%2C%20then%20click%20Printers%20%26%20Scanners.&text=Select%20the%20printer%20in%20the%20list%2C%20then%20click%20the%20Remove%20button%20.

Comment: @simon I don't want to remove it because it's useful when I'm in the office.

Comment: @KoenigLear: do you have any scripts mapped in "Login Items" with printer configuration of the company network? disable it or uncheck it as you mentioned it starts at startup.

Comment: @Udhy actually it's a login item, but how do you temporarily disable it?

Comment: Uncheck any login items that you don't want to run at startup and reboot

Comment: @SteveChambers I don't want to remove it permanently as it's useful for printing in the office

Comment: that doesn't remove it permanently. Just turn it back on my checking the box and reboot. It is still there just turned off.

Comment: @SteveChambers at least in my mac there's only the choice to remove it.

Comment: My apologies, an incorrectly remembered UI feature. My only excuse... Ummm premature senility(?) You may have to remove and re-add it. Perhaps your IT department can point you to the file you need to add/delete. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: @KoenigLear: Are you the admin of the machine?. And don't you have a hide as an option on the right side of it.

Comment: @Udhy I'm an admin of the machine but hide does not mean disable.

Comment: @KoenigLear Hide will disable as temporary and you can enable later easily on your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment, I am writing a solution for you that might be helpful.

**Temporarily Disable Startup Apps**

Enter your login information as you normally would, but hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key on the keyboard before submitting your credentials. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> until the Dock appears, and the startup apps won't load this time.

This is how it works on a password-protected Mac if you don't have proper priviledge on machine to hide/remove the login items.

Comment: Looks interesting but I have other startup items that I do want to run.

Comment: How did you even discover it! +1